# Giving read permission to object uploaded via PutObjectRequest in amazon s3

Tags: java, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I am uploading text file to Amazon s3 bucket via java application. I want to set read access fot that file for everyone. Does anyone know how to do this ? or direct me to some appropriate resources ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can create a bucket policy that make all resources (or those who match a wildcard) available.

Click on your bucket properties on aws S3 console and edit the bucket policy to something like :

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "auniqueid",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Where `bucket` in the `Resource` parameter is your bucket name.

Also you can set public permission for a specific file via Java API :

```
PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, key, file);
por.setCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
s3.putObject(por);
```

Comment: I was looking for java api code. This one worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: For the .Net people the exact line would be `por.CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead;`

Comment: There's a typo in Effect field, it should be "Allow" instead of "Alow"